# Sharepoint Foundation Breadcrumbs styling and layout modification

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, branding

This is really a few questions in one post, but I'd prefer to ask this way as they are both related:

Question 1: In Sharepoint Foundation I'd like to move the breadcrumbs into a visible area on the content page

```
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderMain" runat="server">
                    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

Would the above placehoder be the best area to use? as it does not seem to display it once placed in this area.

I have also placed the breadcrumbs in multiple areas of a sites page(which I am able to view), however once I've moved the sites breadcrumbs: (the below code)

```
<asp:contentplaceholder id="PlaceHolderGlobalNavigation" runat="server">
<SharePoint:PopoutMenu
    runat="server"
    ID="GlobalBreadCrumbNavPopout"
    IconUrl="/_layouts/images/fgimg.png"
    IconAlt="Navigate Up"
    IconOffsetX=0
    IconOffsetY=112
    IconWidth=16
    IconHeight=16
    AnchorCss="s4-breadcrumb-anchor"
    AnchorOpenCss="s4-breadcrumb-anchor-open"
    MenuCss="s4-breadcrumb-menu">
    <div class="s4-breadcrumb-top">
        <asp:Label 
            runat="server" 
            CssClass="s4-breadcrumb-header" 
            Text="This page location is:" />
    </div>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderTitleBreadcrumb" runat="server">
        <SharePoint:ListSiteMapPath
            runat="server"
            SiteMapProviders="SPSiteMapProvider,SPContentMapProvider"
            RenderCurrentNodeAsLink="false"
            PathSeparator=""
            CssClass="s4-breadcrumb"
            NodeStyle-CssClass="s4-breadcrumbNode"
            CurrentNodeStyle-CssClass="s4-breadcrumbCurrentNode"
            RootNodeStyle-CssClass="s4-breadcrumbRootNode"
            NodeImageOffsetX=0
            NodeImageOffsetY=353
            NodeImageWidth=16
            NodeImageHeight=16
            NodeImageUrl="/_layouts/images/fgimg.png"
            RTLNodeImageOffsetX=0
            RTLNodeImageOffsetY=376
            RTLNodeImageWidth=16
            RTLNodeImageHeight=16
            RTLNodeImageUrl="/_layouts/images/fgimg.png"
            HideInteriorRootNodes="true"
            SkipLinkText="" />
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</SharePoint:PopoutMenu>
<div class="s4-die">
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderGlobalNavigationSiteMap" runat="server" Visible="false">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</div>
```

It does not show up on any of the subsites (I assume they are inheriting another type of masterpage)

Id also like to reformat the breadcrumbs into a vertical menu as opposed to the windows explorer type style being currently used.

Waldek covers this in his post here but is there a way to list them horizontally

I've found a few links which seem to point in some sort of direction but thought I'd get some advice before attempting either one (of the links below) and find out which solution would be best.

Also has anyone attempted to use the Mavenation solution at the following link: http://blog.mastykarz.nl/create-sharepoint-breadcrumbs-mavention-simple-sitemappath/

and is it a good idea to use it if you have templates which require 'redeployability'?

It would be appreciated if anyone could assist.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, each "web" has it's own master page setting, so unless you have your subsite set to inherit the master page from the parent, it will have its' own master page selection.

Secondly, as the breadcrumb is simply a collection of unordered list elements, you should be able to easily change their structure to render horizontally with just CSS (as opposed to needing to modify the control). My only "concern" would be that the breadcrumb can potentially get pretty out of control if you're 10 sites deep into your topology, so horizontal rendering may be troublesome on smaller screen resolutions or mobile devices (ie: tablets).

While I haven't done it, you should be able to use `display: inline-block` on the li elements to make them render inline. This would also allow you to include the CSS markup with any other custom CSS for your branding.

Comment: Thanks WebDes03 for the response - I also ended up using the following link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3532367/sharepoint-2010-how-to-apply-custom-master-page-and-theme-to-all-subsites to help me resolve having the subsites pick up the  masterpage changes

Answer (score 0):

I’ve tried the following:

Please note: I’ve inserted this at the beginning of the PlaceHolderMain, right before the XSLTListView showing all Results in the View!

[image]
And obtained the following (with more styling of the elements we could probably reach expected effect –  here already I’ve hidden the Arrow!): - this is a library on one site I’m currently working as Is using Out-of-the-box controls already in SharePoint

[image]